Is averaging RMSE values across cross-validation folds mathematically invalid?
Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that both scikit-learn and tidymodels will average the metrics of choice (RMSE, R2, etc.) across cross-validation folds.  These metrics will be reported and will be the basis for selecting the final model.
RMSE is not additive.  Each fold's RMSE calculation has already applied a square root.  Won't naively averaging RMSE results have the result of adding unnecessary noise to the result?  Leading to worse model selection?
MSE is additive, although sometimes the folds may have different number of observations and a truly rigorous summarization of MSE would require a weighted average with the number of observations.
It seems like the better summarization of cross-validation would be to calculate the metrics across the full set of validation fold observations rather than sloppy summarizations of the individual fold results.
Is this practice chipping away a little bit of model performance across the board?
